# Getting correct values for few inputs. Not for all combinations in a 4*4 multiplier

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a code for 4*4 multiplier. Although, i am getting correct values for few inputs, it gives me wrong values for few other. Please suggest me what logical errors are present here as i am unable to spot them

---

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

    entity multiplier is
        Port ( a : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
               b : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
               result : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
    end multiplier;

    architecture Behavioral of multiplier is

    signal P0: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal P1: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal SP1: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal P2: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal SP2: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal P3: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    component genericadder

            Port ( a : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                   b : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                   sum : out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0));
            end component;  

    begin 

    result(0) <= a(0) and b(0);
    P0(0) <= a(0) and b(1);
    P0(1) <= a(0) and b(2);
    P0(2) <= a(0) and b(3);
    P0(3) <='0';

    P0(4) <= a(1) and b(0);
    P0(5) <= a(1) and b(1);
    P0(6) <= a(1) and b(2);
    P0(7) <= a(1) and b(3);

    ga_for : genericadder
    port map(
     a =>P0( 3 downto 0),
     b =>P0( 7 downto 4),   
     sum =>P1(4 downto 0));    


    result(1)<= P1(0);
    SP1<= std_logic_vector(shift_right(unsigned(P1),1));
    P1(4) <= a(2) and b(0);
    P1(5) <= a(2) and b(1);
    P1(6) <= a(2) and b(2);
    P1(7) <= a(2) and b(3);

    ga_for1 : genericadder
    port map(
     a =>SP1( 3 downto 0),
     b =>P1( 7 downto 4),
     sum =>P2(4 downto 0));

    result(2) <= P2(0);
    SP2<= std_logic_vector(shift_right(unsigned(P2),1));
    P2(4) <= a(3) and b(0);
    P2(5) <= a(3) and b(1);
    P2(6) <= a(3) and b(2);
    P2(7) <= a(3) and b(3);

    ga_for2 : genericadder
    port map(
     a =>SP2( 3 downto 0),
     b =>P2( 7 downto 4),
     sum =>P3(4 downto 0));

    result(3)<=P3(0);


    result(4)<=P3(1);
    result(5)<=P3(2);
    result(6)<=P3(3);
    result(7)<=P3(4);


    end Behavioral;
```

---

---

```
entity genericadder is
 generic (
    n : Integer:=4       
     );
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0);
           sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n downto 0));
end genericadder;
```

--

The genericadder is made up of full adders. Please let me know the error. I am really unable to move ahead

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You'll get better answers if you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's an awful lot of typing. I assume this is some kind of uni project? In industry we'd just type `result <= a * b;`. Anyway, you're going to need to give an awful lot more information for someone to be able to help you. Which values is it failing on? How about providing the testbench? How about reducing it to (say) 2 bits - that's less code to debug and you might spot the error while doing it.

Comment: You are right. Its for a project. I am just testing the module for forcing values to the simulator. Anyway, i shall take your suggestion and implement it for 2 bits.

Comment: Its giving me correct results for 'f' * 'f'. but not 'f' * 'e'

Comment: So, how about editing your question so that it is a [MCVE] for your two-bit version?

Comment: Besides the missing use clause for multiplier's context clause you have signals with multiple drivers. That implies your *wrong values for few other* includes metavalues on result. If you provide a [mcve] an answer can be useful to future readers as well. Without the MCVe your problem and the solution can't be verified.